# Dropdown-nav retirar o "hover" e aparecer listagem completa dos menus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo, navegador-de-internet

Boas pessoal,

Estou com outra dificuldade que não estou a conseguir resolver, o meu menu dropdown funciona com hover, mas quando fica com o toogle gostava que os submenus em x de ficarem a aparecer com o hover ficassem tipo listagem, mas não estou a conseguir

Segue a imagem de como está a ficar,

Já tentei retirar o display: none nos media querys mas ao fazer isso o menu fica sobreposto

Alguma ajuda?

Obrigado!

[Imagem com hover a aparecer sobreposto ao menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETG1J.jpg)

[Imagem representativa de como gostava que ficasse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1lkL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Esconde todos e abra apenas o que está sendo clicado.

```
$('#menu > li').hide();
$(this).addClass('show');
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado, mas eu quero que apareçam todos em lista em vez de me ficar por cima dos menus, basicamente queria uma lista vertical dos menus todo.